# Globally installed package command files generated oddly

Tags: node.js, npm

I've been working on a [command line program](https://github.com/ShaneK/BlueStacksProfiles) and I'm having a problem trying to get it to install globally.

I set up the bin in the package.json so it looks like

```
"bin" : { "bsp" : "bsp.js" }
```

Whenever it generates the command files in %appdata%/npm though, it generates them like this:

bsp

```
"$basedir/node_modules/BlueStacksProfiles/bsp.js"   "$@"
exit $?
```

bsp.cmd

```
"%~dp0\node_modules\BlueStacksProfiles\bsp.js"   %*
```

Notice it's missing the node command in both of them, and in the first one it doesn't set the basedir properly (which is bad because if you try to run it from git bash it'll assume the wrong basedir).

As opposed to say, [http-server](https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-server)

http-server

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

http-server.cmd

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server" %*
) ELSE (
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server" %*
)
```

and that's just the generic template, all other globally installed npm apps I have installed look something like that. I feel like I'm missing something from my package.json, but I can't find much material on creating globally installed node apps.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried changing the package to "bin" : { "bsp" : "./bsp.js" } and also just "bin" : "./bsp.js" but neither of those do anything different. I really think I must be missing something simple from package.json or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, for anybody else having this problem, it was because my bin file didn't start with

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Adding that fixed the problem.